# How to preserve formatting for C++ streams?

Tags: c++, formatting, stream

I have the following code (simplified):

```
ostringstream oss;

oss << "Text ";

oss << hex << uppercase;
oss.width(8);
oss.fill('0');

oss << var1 << " ";
oss << var2 << " ";

oss << dec << nouppercase;
oss.width(1);

oss << var3 << " another text." << endl;

string result = oss.str();
// work with result...
```

Where `var1`, `var2` are `unsigned int`'s and `var3` is an `int`. The idea is to create a string where `var1` and `var2` are formated like a hex number (but without the `0x`) and `var3` as a regular integer. What i found out that only the first number is correctly formated, the second one is not padded with zeroes:

```
Text 000AF00C 3B7FF 1 another text.
```

After a while i found out that setting the width and fill parameters AGAIN fixes this. Is there a way how to avoid specifying these formating rules over and over again for each number? The amount of formatted variables is much higher than 2, this was just a simplified example. Wrapping all this into a function is an option, but i would really like to learn how to preserve the formatting with `ostringstream`.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just the `width` that is reset as this would be a bug in your implementation?

Comment: Maybe it's just the width, didn't test width/fill separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry some settings for stream formatting are called volatile (has nothing to do with the keyword), you have to set it each time. [See here for explanation.](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html)

It will be best to create your own functions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way how to avoid specifying these formating rules over and over again for each number?

No, [there are manipulators which are sticky and there are those which are not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky). Those that are not have to be repeated for every output.

BTW, you can apply some syntactic sugar and turn

```
oss.width(8);
oss.fill('0');

oss << var1 << " ";
```

into

```
oss << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << var1 << " ";
```

Comment: I think it is misleading to make a sticky / unsticky distinction. All the manipulators have the same effect: they set something on the stream object; it's just that the act of performing a number of formatted output operations is required to call (or have the effect of calling) `.width(0)` as an explicit part of the operation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky/1533752#1533752

Comment: @Charles: It seems the question I linked to was later changed to reflect exactly that.

Comment: You mean the accepted answer? Yes, after a looong comment exchange.

Answer (score 1):

As always, write  a function:

```
void WriteHex( unsigned int n, ostream & os  ) {
  os << hex << uppercase;
  os.width(8);
  os.fill('0');
  os << n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your format settings should be preserved except for `width` which is only preserved until the next formatted output operation. This is because formatted output functions are required to call `width(0)` as a side effect.

A reasonably succinct solution would be to use the `setw` manipulator before the output operations that require a non-zero width.

Note that you might be surprised at the output for this if you've set the fill character and a width of 8 was preserved from the last numeric output.

```
os << " ";
```