# How to clear width when outputting from a stream, after using std::setw?

Tags: c++, stringstream, iomanip, setw

I'm using a std::stringstream to parse a fixed format string into values.  However the last value to be parsed is not fixed length.

To parse such a string I might do:

```
std::stringstream ss("123ABCDEF1And then the rest of the string");
ss >> std::setw(3) >> nId
   >> std::setw(6) >> sLabel
   >> std::setw(1) >> bFlag
   >> sLeftovers;
```

But how do I set the width such that the remainder of the string is output?

Through trial and error I found that doing this works:

```
   >> std::setw(-1) >> sLeftovers;
```

But what's the correct approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Roll-Back" or Undo Any Manipulators Applied To A Stream Without Knowing What The Manipulators Were](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217704/roll-back-or-undo-any-manipulators-applied-to-a-stream-without-knowing-what-th)

Comment: "by doing this works: `std::setw(-1)`"  do you mean that `sLeftovers` contains the value 'And' or 'And then the rest of the string'? I find the 'std::setw(-1)` retrieves just the word "And", i.e. the same result as '>> sLeftovers' - it has no affect which is consistent with the documentation for `std::setw` which states that `std::setw` sets the number of characters to be used as the field for the next insertion operation.

Comment: You're quite right Mark, in my actual code there was no space in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the input operator `>>` stops reading at whitespace.

Use e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get the remainder of the string:

```
std::stringstream ss("123ABCDEF1And then the rest of the string");
ss >> std::setw(3) >> nId
   >> std::setw(6) >> sLabel
   >> std::setw(1) >> bFlag;
std::getline(ss, sLeftovers);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::setw` only affects exactly one operation, i.e. `>> bFlag` will reset it to default, so you don't need to do anything to reset it.

i.e. your code should just work

```
std::stringstream ss("123ABCDEF1And then the rest of the string");
ss >> std::setw(3) >> nId
   >> std::setw(6) >> sLabel
   >> std::setw(1) >> bFlag
   >> sLeftovers;
```

Comment: It doesn't, sLeftovers in my code is 1 char "A" (of the "And...").  Are you sure std::setw "only affects exactly one operation"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::stringstream ss("123ABCDEF1And then the rest of the string");
std::stringstream::streamsize initial = ss.width(); // backup
ss >> std::setw(3) >> nId
   >> std::setw(6) >> sLabel
   >> std::setw(1) >> bFlag
   >> sLeftovers;

ss.width(initial); // restore
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that `setw(-1)` actually works for you because I haven't seen this documented, and when I tried your code on VC10, I only got "And" for `sLeftovers`. I'd probably use `std::getline( ss, sLeftovers )` for the remainder of the string, which worked for me in VC10.