# Dealing with iostream manipulators and ANSI console color codes

Tags: c++, c++11, console, iostream, manipulators

I'm using ANSI color codes to format my output in an Unix console.

```
const auto& getCode(Color mColor) 
{
    static std::map<Color, std::string> codes;
    // ...
    return codes[mColor]
}

cout << getCode(Color::Red) << "red text";
```

When using manipulators such as `std::setw` or `std::left`, however, the results are affected by the color code, as it is a bunch of characters.

*How should I deal with this issue? Is there a way to make stream manipulators ignore color codes?*

Comment: You mean passing them through unchanged without effect on anything else? What's the definition of `getCode`?

Comment: Does your function returns int or char? Please share the getCode prototype with us.

Comment: Is getCode a struct with output stream operator? Maybe you are interested in setting and restoring iostream flags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217704/roll-back-or-undo-any-manipulators-applied-to-a-stream-without-knowing-what-th

Comment: @Sven: Better a function which returns a streamable `struct`.

Comment: I suspect you mean **ANSI** color codes? ASCII doesn't define colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the type returned by `getCode`?  If it isn't
`std::string` or `char const*`, all you need to do is write
a `<<` for it which ignores the formatting data you don't want
to affect it.  If it's one of C++'s string types, then you
should probably wrap the call in a special object, with an `<<`
for that object type, e.g.:

```
class ColorCode
{
    ColorType myColor;
public:
    ColorCode(ColorType color) : myColor( color ) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, ColorCode const& cc )
    {
        std::string escapeSequence = getCode( myColor );
        for ( char ch : escapeSequence ) {
            dest.put( ch );
        }
        return dest;
    }
};
```

Comment: I suspect it returns `"\x1B[41m"`. I agree that your idea is better, you'd be able to just write `cout << Color::Red << "red text";`

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so simple. I was already testing an implementation of a cache stream that sorted formatting strings and color codes... turns out you just need a simple wrapper class!