# How to remove redundancy in formatted ofstream

Tags: c++, c++98

I have the following working code which produces formatted output using an ofstream, however I feel that all of the repeated format specifiers make it hard to read. Is there any way to set the precision, width and alignment permanently for a given stream, which would clean things up nicely?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> 

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(Output.c_str(), ios::trunc);
for (int i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
   myfile <<std::fixed << std::setw( iWidth ) << std::setprecision( iDecimals )<< std::right << pDist[i]  << "   "
      <<std::fixed << std::setw( iWidth ) << std::setprecision( iDecimals )<< std::right << pRes[i]   << "   "
      <<std::fixed << std::setw( iWidth ) << std::setprecision( iDecimals )<< std::right << pPhase[i] << "\n";
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the repeated format specifiers? Most format specifiers are persisted until they are explicitly changed again.

Comment: `std::fixed`, `std::setprecision`, and `std::right` are all "permanent". The only one that you need every time is `setw`.

Comment: @CalvinScherle is right. I had tried removing the specifiers as suggested by Code-Apprentice, but that didn't work because I was removing all of them. Thanks Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::fixed`, `std::setprecision`, and `std::right` are all "permanent". They set persistent flags on the stream object.

The only one that you need to put every time is `setw`, which (as I understand) does not set a flag on the stream *object*, just adds a certain amount of whitespace by altering the stream itself. But it leaves the stream alone.

This is similar to `endl`, which operates on the stream but leaves the actual stream object alone.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533222/4116647) by @LokiAstari on a similar question details which specifiers are, as they put it, "sticky" (and why).

**EDIT:** Cleared up distinctions between the stream object and the actual stream

Answer (score 2):

The only manipulator you need to worry about is [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) as the width is set back to zero whenever `operator<<` is called. Before your loop, you can set your "permanent" ios flags:

```
myfile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(iDecimals) << std::right;
for (int i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
   myfile << std::setw( iWidth ) << pDist[i] << "   "
      << std::setw( iWidth ) << pRes[i] << "   "
      << std::setw( iWidth ) << pPhase[i] << "\n";
}
```

If you want to unset these flags in one go, you can use:

```
std::cout.copyfmt(std::ios(NULL));
```

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217811/3920237).