# Isnt setprecision not supposed to change the value stored in variable?

Tags: c++

I was of the opinion that setprecision doesnt change the value in variable itself. Also, when you attach setprecision to cout, it sticks with it only once. However, when I run code to verify, it doesnt work.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    double x = 9.87654321;
    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << x <<endl;    //Returns 9.877 as it should
    cout << x << endl;                               //Returns truncated value 9.877 again though it shouldnt.

    return 0;
}
```

Interesting part is, if we replace `cout << x << endl;` by a line setting precision to say 7, then it DOES display the correct value. Can anyone please explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky/1533752#1533752

Answer (score 5):

You don't reset the precision to the original value so it's just using 3 as the precision value for both output operations.

If you want to restore the original precision then you need to save it. The initial value for standard `ostream`s is 6 which may not be accurate enough for many purposes.

```
int main()
{
    double x = 9.87654321;

    size_t save_prec = cout.precision();
    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << x <<endl;
    cout.precision(save_prec);

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sets the precision of the output stream, not `x`, meaning after the call to `setprecision(3)`, `cout` outputs all numbers with precision of 3.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/

Try this, which will show that x has not changed.

```
int main() 
{     
  double x = 9.87654321;     
  cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << x <<endl;    //Returns 9.877 as it should     
  cerr << x << endl;                               //Returns 9.87654 to stderr  
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: So in that case, If I do something like y=x, after setting precision to 3 and then print y, it should print the complete value? But then I tried it and it doesnt!

Comment: Horrible fix. `cout` and `cerr` are completely different streams and have different purposes -- just because they sometimes map to the same output doesn't mean they're interchangeable.

Comment: @John: not a fix, just an example.  I wasn't implying they were the same.

Comment: @Scranton: That's because you are probably still using `cout`, which still has a precision of 3 after the call to `setprecision`.

Comment: @James: Sorry, slight misunderstanding on my part -- although I still think it's somewhat misleading.

Comment: Does this mean, that if you use setprecision once, it sticks to all cout usages you make in the future? I was of the misinformed opinion that setprecision doesnt stick to cout unless you specify it every single time.

Comment: @Scranton: You may be thinking of `width()`. Most formatted output functions automatically reset the `width()` to 0. No other formatting flags are reset by the usual formatted output functions.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have indicated the problem. One possible solution is to use the [Boost I/O Stream state saver](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) library to do the work of saving the I/O stream formatting state and restoring it at the appropriate time.