# What's the opposite of `fixed` in cout?

Tags: c++, cout, formatter, iomanip

When using `cout`, what is the default formatter defined in the `<iomanip>` header? In other words, once I've set my formatter to `fixed` using `cout << fixed << setPrecision(2)`, how do I change it back? Or, what am I changing it back *to*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opposite of `std::fixed` is `std::scientific`.

(You find a nice list of manipulators in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky/1533222#1533222).)

Comment: The default float and the scientific notation are different. It is not exactly "changing it back".

Answer (score 17):

The answer is `std::defaultfloat` in C++11. To achieve this in C++03 you can do

`cout.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);`

See [Really, what's the opposite of "fixed" I/O manipulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035131/really-whats-the-opposite-of-fixed-i-o-manipulator/)

Comment: `cout.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);` this working with C++11 but not `std::defaultfloat`

Comment: and also `cout.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);` why it only reverse the effect of `fixed` as it not include any keyword like `fixed` means why it not reset `precision` also

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`resetiosflags()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/resetiosflags/) to unset any flags.

Comment: Is there a "default" that I can set to?

Comment: I believe the default is `std::ios::scientific`.

Comment: @Moshe: Unfortunately, there is no simple way to fully reset a stream. Even the most elaborate code I have seen to do that (by James Kanze, more than a decade ago) misses on some esoteric propertiesm, like `iword` and `pword`. (Of course, James was fully aware of the limitations.) You can, however, get pretty far with [`std::ios::flags()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/flags/).

Comment: The easiest way to reset a stream is to default construct it.  In some cases it may make sense to format your output in an `ostringstream` and then just send the already formatted output to `cout` as a `std::string`.  It may be more costly to do it this way (output is not usually a place where I spend a lot of time optimizing or investigating performance issues, as usually other hardware related concerns outweigh any performance decreases).

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of `std::fixed` is `std::scientific`. That might do for you.

However, if you want to restore more flags, or if you need the *previous* state, instead of the default you can use better solutions:

1. the `std::resetiosflags` manipulator lets you reset specific flags to their defaults;
2. the two `ios::flags` functions let you save and restore the previous values of the format flags.

Comment: uhm, in the sense of "go back to default" the opposite of `std::fixed` is not `std::scientific`. it is more like an automatic format-switching mode.