# Really, what's the opposite of "fixed" I/O manipulator?

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout, iomanip

This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422200/whats-the-opposite-of-fixed-in-cout), but I don't feel it was actually answered correctly. Observe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  float p = 1.00;
  cout << showpoint << setprecision(3) << p << endl;
}
```

Output: `1.00`

Now if we change that line to:

```
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(3) << p << endl;
```

we get: `1.000`

And if we use the "opposite" of fixed we get something totally different:

```
  cout << scientific << showpoint << setprecision(3) << p << endl;
```

Output: `1.000e+00`

How can I go back to the behaviour of the first version after `fixed` has been set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format specification for floating points is a bitmask call `std::ios_base::floatfield`. In C++03 it has two named settings (`std::ios_base::fixed` and `std::ios_base::scientific`). The default setting is to have neither of these flags set. This can be achieved, e.g., using

```
stream.setf(std::ios_base::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::floatfield);
```

or

```
stream.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
```

(the type of the field is `std::ios_base::fmtflags`).

With the current C++ there is also `std::ios_base::hexfloat` and there are two manipulators added, in particular `std::defaultfloat()` which clears the `std::ios_base::floatfield`:

```
stream << std::defaultfloat;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is `std::defaultfloat`. However, this is only available in C++11. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Before C++11, you can clear the `fixed` flag, but not with a manipulator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float p = 1.00;
    cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(3) << p << endl;

    // change back to default:
    cout.setf(0, ios::fixed);
    cout << showpoint << setprecision(3) << p << endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::ios_base::fmtflags {aka std::_Ios_Fmtflags}' [-fpermissive])