# Weird memory overwrite issues causing integers to become hex numbers

Tags: c++, memory-management, hex

I am in the midst of debugging someone's code, and I have code like

```
int i = their_val;
std::cout << "output: " << i << std::endl;
```

When I look at the log output I see lines like

```
output: a
```

Should this happen? Is something changing the cout formatting or could it be something odder?

Comment: "causing integers to become hex numbers" is a phrase to think about... those poor integers.

Comment: As the answers below have noted, a preceding `std::hex` is causing the issue. See this previous discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky

Answer (score 3):

Did someone `cout << std::hex` prior to that output?  It would cause it to print in hexadecimal.

Comment: I think it's probably that (upvoted) but it's a huge enough code base that I can't immediately find it. I realised this was probably the case just after submitting...

Answer (score 3):

Check and see if `std::hex` gets passed into std::cout anywhere. That would result in the behavior you're seeing.

You can force things to be in decimal using:

```
std::cout << "output: " << std::dec << i << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did `std::cout << std::hex` somewhere earlier. You can undo this with `std::cout << std::dec`.

```
std::cout << "output: " << std::dec << i << std::endl;
```