# std::istreambuf_iterator<char> initializes with no arguments?

Tags: c++, io, binaryfiles

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
{
    std::ifstream in(name, std::ios_base::binary);
    bytes.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in >> std::noskipws),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}
```

According to the reference, the `vector.assign` function takes two arguments, `first` and `last`, and takes anything in between into the vector. And the istreambuf_iterator function takes this form:

```
istreambuf_iterator( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& is );    
istreambuf_iterator( std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* s );
```

These are all easy to understand, but in the snippet above, the second iterator initializer takes no arguments, what does it mean?

Also notice that the type of `bytes` is `unsigned char`, while the type of the iterator is `char`, isn't this a mismatch?

Comment: The default constructor makes an end of stream iterator. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/istreambuf_iterator).

Comment: And there's an implicit conversion from `char` to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the second iterator initializer takes no arguments, what does it mean?

It means it's initialized to be the end-of-stream iterator.

> Also notice that the type of `bytes` is `unsigned int`, while the type of the iterator is `char`, isn't this a mismatch?

You mean `unsigned char` right? (That's what it says in your code.)

It's fine because `unsigned char` can be constructed from and assigned from `char`. Templated functions taking iterator ranges generally do not require that the types match exactly. (For the precise requirements, see Table 100 in §23.2.3 of the standard.)

Comment: In this case, if I just want to read two bytes, what argument should I give to istreambuf_iterator?

Comment: @qed I don't believe there's a nice way to do that. Just write a loop.