# Printing hex and int together in a text file

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to print hex values for member[0] and member[1] and integer values for _records in the same text file with the following code:

```
 std::ofstream myoutputfile;

 myoutputfile << std::hex << (int)(unsigned char)_member[0] << ' ';

 myoutputfile << std::hex << (int)(unsigned char)_member[1] << ' ';

 myoutputfile<<_records << std::endl;
```

But this code prints _records in hex too. I have tried:

```
myoutputfile<<(int)_records << std::endl;
```

But still it prints it in hex.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base that's use for conversion from numbers to text is a state of the output stream rather than a function of the input type.  You need to do:

```
myoutputfile<< std::dec << _records << std::endl;
```

This changes the state of the output stream to put _records using decimal.

Comment: Nitpick: this behavior doesn't really have to do with the state being associated with the stream object rather than the object being written to the stream. If that were the case [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) would persist too, but that resets after most formatted input/output. The rest of them persist because they're required to do so. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533222/241631) answer.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  My point wasn't that the radix state wasn't necessarily reset after the next invocation of stream << data, but rather that the (int) cast couldn't possibly reset the radix state.

Answer (score 4):

Set the format back to decimal using `std::dec`

```
myoutputfile<< std::dec << _records << std::endl;
```

As you've discovered, the base format specifiers are *sticky*, so there's no need to specify `std::hex` each time. Your code could be rewritten as follows to achieve the same effect.

```
std::ofstream myoutputfile;
myoutputfile << std::hex 
  << (int)(unsigned char)_member[0] << ' '
  << (int)(unsigned char)_member[1] << ' '
  << std::dec << _records << std::endl;
```

---

You could also have the resetting to previous state done automatically by using [Boost IO State Savers](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html#example).

```
#include <boost/io/ios_state.hpp>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int  main()
{
    auto hex_printer = [](std::ostream& os, unsigned char byte) {
        boost::io::ios_flags_saver  ifs(os);
        os << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(byte) << ' ';
    };

    hex_printer(std::cout, 'A');
    std::cout << 42 << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cacf3bdabc28ad09)

Answer (score 1):

`std::hex` tells an `ostream` to print everything in hex from that point on. The equivalent that will return it to decimal is `std::dec`. Try the following:

```
std::ofstream myoutputfile;
myoutputfile << std::hex;
myoutputfile << _member[0] << ' ';
myoutputfile << _member[1] << ' ';
myoutputfile << std::dec << _records << std::endl;
```

Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/ as an additional reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fprintf, which prints formatted text:

```
frintf("%x %x %d\n",_member[0],_member[0],_records);
```

Hope this helps