# iomanip with an object of a class

Tags: c++

In a C++ program I have some code to print an object of a class called fraction. Its variables are n (the numerator), d (the denominator) and sinal (signal: true when a fraction is positive and false otherwise).

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const fraction &x){//n=0

    if(!x.sinal)
        os << "-";

    os << x.n;

    if(x.d!=1 && x.n!=0)
        os << "/" << x.d;

    return os;
}
```

It does a good job, but when I try to use a setw() in it, it doesn't work properly: it just affects the first item to be printed (whether it's the signal or the numerator).

I tried to change it and the solution I found was first to convert it to a string and then using the os with a iomanip:

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const fraction &x){//n=0

    string xd, xn;

    stringstream ssn;
    ssn << x.n;
    ssn >> xn;

    stringstream ssd;
    ssd << x.d;
    ssd >> xd;

    string sfra = "";

    if(!x.sinal)
        sfra += "-";

    sfra += xn;

    if(x.d !=1 && x.n != 0){
        sfra += "/";
        sfra += xd;
    }

    os << setw (7) << left << sfra;

    return os;
}
```

This works, but obviously I'm not able to change the width that a fraction will have: it will be 7 for all of them. Is there a way to change that? I really need to use different widths for different fractions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533752 , the `width` of the output is explicitly reset for each formatted output.

What you could do is at the start of your function get the current width, which is the width set by `std::setw` (or related), and then set this width explicitly for each value where you want it applied and use `std::setw(0)` for each value that you want to output as-is:

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const fraction &x)
{
    std::streamsize width = os.width();

    if(!x.sinal)
        os << std::setw(width) << "-";
    else
        os << std::setw(width); // Not necessary, but for explicitness.

    os << x.n;

    if(x.d!=1 && x.n!=0)
        os << "/" << std::setw(width) << x.d;

    return os;
}
```

Now you need to improve upon this a bit to handle left and right padding; this only handles left-padding.