# How to cout middle zero with leading zero via one cout statement in C++?

Tags: c++, leading-zero

I need to display three values which is parsed from packet binary data(0x123400005678).

```
unsigned int k = 0x1234, l=0x0, m=0x5678;
```

I can display with four-digit hex value when I use cout three times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
...
cout << "seperated cout" << endl;
cout << hex << setfill ('0') << setw (4) << k;
cout << hex << setfill ('0') << setw (4) << l;
cout << hex << setfill ('0') << setw (4) << m << endl;
....

seperated cout
123400005678
```

But when I use only one cout line, leading zero of '0x0' is omitted...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
...
cout << "oneline cout" << endl;
cout << hex << setfill ('0') << setw (4) << k << l << m << endl;
...

oneline cout
123405678
```

Is there anyway to display like '123400005678' with one line cout?
Or is using cout three times only way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ultimately the answer for you will be provided here: ["Which io manipulators are sticky?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky). The short of it is, `std::setw` only affects the *next* output datum. The linked question dives in to considerably more than that, discussing *all* manipulators and their sticky-or-not effects.

Comment: Thank @WhozCraig . It is helpful to understand the 'sticky' of manipulators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field width isn't "sticky", so you need to set it again for each field you print out:

```
cout << hex << setfill ('0') << setw (4) << k << setw(4) << l << setw(4) << m << endl;
```

Result:

```
123400005678
```

The fill character *is* sticky though, so you usually want to set it back to a space character as soon as you're done using whatever other value you set:

```
cout << setfill(' ');
```

Comment: Nice one @Jerry coffin :)