# How can I make my function sticky for overloaded iostream extraction operators

Tags: c++, windows, console, iomanip

I'm doing a school project in which I need to change text colour frequently.
Project target is Console app currently for Windows only. Using Codeblocks with MinGW for Debugging.
I'm not a noob, but Intermediate-ish.

So using this everywhere in the code was ugly:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), __col._colour_code);
```

Even if I wrapped it in a function, it still is cumbersome and ugly because you cannot continue your cout chain. You have break the chain as you must call the `SetColour` in a new statement, e.g.:

```
SetColour(GRAY);   cout << setcol(PURPLE) << " ID:[";
SetColour(AQUA);   cout << song.GetID();
SetColour(GRAY);   cout << "]" << " ";
SetColour(GREEN);  cout << song.GetTitle();
SetColour(WHITE);  cout << " by ";
SetColour(BRIGHT); cout << song.GetArtist() << "\n";
```

What I wanted was a functionality like that of `setw`, `setprecision`, etc. So I opened the `iomainp.h` and looked for some hints:

```
struct _Setw { int _M_n; };

inline _Setw 
setw(int __n)
{ return { __n }; }

template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
inline basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _Setw __f)
{
  __is.width(__f._M_n);
  return __is; 
}

template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, _Setw __f)
{
  __os.width(__f._M_n);
  return __os; 
}
```

So I created a new function of my own in a 100% analogous way:

```
enum Colour { BLACK=0x00, DARK_GREEN=0x02, WHITE=0x07, GRAY,
              BLUE=0x09, GREEN, AQUA, RED, PURPLE, YELLOW, BRIGHT };

struct _colour_struct
{
    uint8_t _colour_code;
};

inline _colour_struct setcolour (Colour colour_foregrnd, Colour colour_backgrnd =BLACK)
{
    uint8_t colour_code = colour_backgrnd;
    colour_code <<= 4;
    colour_code |= colour_foregrnd;
    return { colour_code };
}

namespace std
{
    template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, _colour_struct __col)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), __col._colour_code);
        return __os;
    }
}
```

SURPRISE! (for me) Its working!! e.g.:

```
cout << setcolour(GRAY) << " ID:[" << setcolour(AQUA) << song.GetID() << setcolour(GRAY) << "]" << " "
     << setcolour(GREEN) << song.GetTitle()
     << setcolour(WHITE) << " by "<< setcolour(BRIGHT) << song.GetArtist() << "\n";
```

But consider the output of this code:

```
std::cout << std::setw(20) << setcolour(AQUA) << "1st time" << "\n";
std::cout << "2nd time" << "\n";
std::cout << "3rd time" << "\n";
```

Notice that `setw` DIDN'T stick, it was Reset in the second line. How ??
(Debugging showed no extra call being executed to reset it.)

But my `setcolour` DID stick for rest of the program. Why ??
(Although its 100% analogous to `setw`).

**How can I make `setcolour` just like `setw`???** I need this functionality to make my program more clean and logical.

Also I found this:
[Which iomanip manipulators are sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky)

But the answers and comments just there only confused me. Apperently, `setw` calls cout.width(0), but debugging showed no such call, nor such a line of code was found in `iomanip.h`. Also didn't understand the answer there. Please explain.

**EDIT**

Maybe I wasn't direct in asking the question.
Like `cout.width(0)` (in context of `setw`) gets called each time,

**How can I make my `SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x0)` (in context of `setcolour`) get called each time ???**
How should I approach this problem ??

Comment: What are you using to display the output? A linux terminal? If so, setting up the color/font is just a matter of printing out a tag. And the text should keep the formatting until you explicitly print another tag.

Comment: The width for a stream gets reset after every write, which is why `setw` is "non-stick". Since apparently every other iomanip is "sticky", it's probably best to keep `setcolour` how it is. The only other thing I can think of is write a wrapper for the output streams.

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 I am just curious.. does changing the order of call to `std::cout << setcolour(AQUA) << std::setw(20) << "1st time" << "\n";` cause any change to the output..?

Comment: @Minato What do you mean ?

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 calling you `cout` like that in the comment.. cause change to the output?. P.S. I am not answering the question but merely curious..

Comment: @Minato Like changing order of "1st time", "2nd time", "3rd time" cout lines ?? Then yes it obviously does. In whichever line the setcolour is called, the setting sticks for the rest of the program, but not for the setw.

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 Nope. just changing this line `std::cout << std::setw(20) << setcolour(AQUA) << "1st time" << "\n";` to this `std::cout << setcolour(AQUA) << std::setw(20) << "1st time" << "\n";` but I got my answer below :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width is handled specially: all of the built-in operators will reset the width after outputting an object. The fact that you don't see a corresponding call to `width(0)` in the code or the debugger doesn't mean it isn't there! It may be inlined and not hit a breakpoint, for exampke. With respect to the code you'd need to look, e.g., in the implementation of `std::num_put<...>`: the actual output operator doesn't include the code but the `do_put()` functions do.

To reset other formatting flags you'd need to hook into some operation called after each output operation. There isn't much opportunity, though: the streams din't support generic customization after each object. Below are things which *can* be done but I would recomment leaving formatting flags sticky. It is arguably a mistake to make the width special:

- The numeric formatting is done via the `do_put()` virtual functions in `std::num_put<cT>`. These functiins can be overridden and, e.g., do the normal formatting by delegating to the base class implementation, followed by something else.

  The key problem with this approach in your setting is that it does not work with non-numeric output. For example, outputting strings wouldn't reset anything.
- It is possible to set the formatting flag `std::unitbuf` causing a flush after each [correctly written] output operator. The flush is translated into a call of `pubsync()` and eventually `sync()` on the streams `std::basic_streambuf<cT>`. The `sync()` function can be overridden. That is, the approach would be installing a custom stream buffer and the flag `std::ios_base::unitbuf` when setting up sone flags which sends output to the original stream and on call to `sync()` resets flags.

  Aside from being a bit contrived it has the problem that you can't distinguish a genuine flush from the automatic flush (the primary purpose of `srd::ios_base::unitbuf` is to get `std::cerr` flushed). Also, the reset happens on the first `std::ostream::sentry` being destroyed. For composite values that is most likely after the first portion being formatted.
- The colour formatter uses a temporary object anyway. The dstructor of this object could be used to reset some fornatting flags. The output operator would set the necessary stream information on the corresponding object when it get "formatted" (probably using a `mutable` member). Of course, this means that setting the format and output need to be done from the same statement. Also, all output on the same statement receives the same format.

I'm not aware of any other approach to deal with formatting after some output. None of the approaches works particular well. I'd rather use a guard-like approach to set/unset flags than trying to be clever.

Comment: Yeah, the sticky version seems more useful now. Your solutions are out of my league for now anyway. I think its best to use the set/unset approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice that setw DIDN'T stick, it was Reset in the second line. How ??

When you use `cout << setcolour(AQUA)`, you are making a persistent change to the state of your program that is used later on.

That is not the case with `std::setw()`. `std::setw()` only sets the width of the next output and then resets the width to zero. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw for more details. In particular, the **Notes**:

> The width property of the stream will be reset to zero (meaning "unspecified") if any of the following functions are called:
>
> - Input
>
>   - `operator>>(basic_istream&, basic_string&)`
>   - `operator>>(basic_ostream&, char*)`
> - Output
>
>   - Overloads 1-7 of `basic_ostream::operator<<()` (at Stage 3 of `num_put::put()`)
>   - `operator<<(basic_ostream&, char)` and `operator<<(basic_ostream&, char*)`
>   - `operator<<(basic_ostream&, basic_string&)`
>   - `std::put_money` (inside `money_put::put())`
>   - `std::quoted` (when used with an output stream)

Comment: OK, that explains `setw`, but the debuuger DID NOT show cout.width(0) being executed nor there was such a line in `iomanip'.
ALSO, HOW DO I MAKE MINE RESET EVERYTIME !!