# cout prints the incorrect value

Tags: c++, hex, cin, cout

So, I'm trying to make a basic C++ program that converts Base 10 -> Base 16

```
while(true){
    int input;
    cout << "Enter the base 10 number\n";
    cin >> input;
    cout << "The hex form of " << input << " is: ";
    int decimal = input;
    cout << hex << uppercase << decimal << "\n";
    decimal = NULL;
    input = NULL;
    Sleep(3000);
}
```

And on the first run through it works. For example, if I enter 7331 I get:

```
The hex form of 7331 is 1CA3
```

But if I try it a second time (with the same input) I get:

```
The hex form of 1CA3 is 1CA3
```

I can try this with any integer input and it works fine for the first run through but after that it puts the base 16 number in twice.

Comment: It's not actually my code, I just wanted to show it was contained in a loop. Let me fix

Comment: Close-voter: what is unclear about this? I find the question to be very clear, OP has mentioned their inputs, outputs and what they expect. The example is more-or-less complete.

Comment: Some stream manipulators are [sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky), some are not. `std::hex` is _sticky_.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset your stream. When you apply `std::hex` to `std::cout`, it applies permanently to the stream (std::cout), and you need to reset it. You can simply change your program to this:

```
cout << "The hex form of " << std::dec << input << " is: ";
```

Answer (score 0):

your FIX:

```
cout << "The hex form of "<< dec << input << " is: ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even shorten your code:

```
while (true)
{
    int input;

    cout << "Enter the base 10 number: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << "The hex form of " << dec << input << " is: ";
    cout << hex << uppercase << input << "\n";

    Sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I originally had it. I added the other stuff to try and 'clear' my variables.