# Extra space/char when using setfill() and setw(), Output changed after printing again

Tags: c++, iomanip, setw

Im a student and we are only allowed to use what we are taught. Our professor only taught us setfill(), setw(), left, right for . Ive been trying to print my code as a box with setfill() and setw() but there is an extra space or char in the output and I dont know why. When calling a function and returning, the 2nd setfill() and set() pair changed the output.

I tried moving things around but when I call a different function and go back it brings outputs an extra char/space. I expect a '|' char then 80 '-' char then ending with another '|' char. After calling a function and returning, the output changed  to be 2 '|' char then 80 '-' char. I tried maybe including more endl, changing positions of setw() and setfill(), adding left, right. Nothing changed.

Snippet of the code function to print:

```
void charChoicesList(char& charChoice, householdList houseArray[], int countArray, householdList sortedArray[])
{

    do {
        cout << setw(50) << "[Please choose a category]" << endl;
        cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(80) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ');
        
        cout << setw(80) << left << "|A. Print all Data" << "|\n"
             << setw(80) << left << "|B. List Identification code of households with income greater than the average" << "|\n"
             << setw(80) << left << "|C. Determine the percentage of households having an income below poverty level" << "|\n"
             << setw(80) << left << "|D. Print all Data sorted by household income" << "|\n"
             << setw(80) << left << "|E.Calculate and print the median household income" << "|\n"
             << setw(80) << left << "|F.Exit Program" << "|" << endl;

        cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(80) << "-" << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << endl;

        cin >> charChoice;

        switch (charChoice) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            cout << "A. Print all Data\n" << endl;
            printData(houseArray, countArray);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            cout << "B. List Identification code of households with income greater than the average\n" << endl;
            calcAverageList(houseArray, countArray);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            cout << "C. Determine the percentage of households having an income below poverty level\n" << endl;
            povertyPercent(houseArray, countArray);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            cout << "D. Print all Data sorted by household income\n" << endl;
            printSorted(houseArray, countArray, sortedArray);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            cout << "E. Calculate and print the median household income\n" << endl;
            calculateMedian(houseArray, countArray, sortedArray);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            cout << "F. Exit Program\n" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Input Error!\n" << endl;

        }
    } while (charChoice != 'f' && charChoice != 'F');

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Ideally the program won't require any input but if it does be sure to include that. Show us what the correct output should look like and what the current output is.

Comment: Just looking at the first few lines of your code here https://godbolt.org/z/noj1aWGfP You have one line that is too long to fit and you're printing an extra `-` in the bottom line. Look at line 9 and 19 and see if you can spot the difference.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok I see the problem. Another thing is for the 2nd pair of setfill() setw() I want to understand why if I change the '-' char to ' ' it would change to having 1 space then 80 '-'. Why does it do that instead of filling 80 '-' in the first place?

Comment: Because the lines before it set `left` which puts the fill on the right side. You need to set it back to `right` if you want the fill before what you print.

Comment: Ohhh. so the "left" from before affects the next lines? I thought it only affects the first output it gets. gotcha. thanks. I fixed it now and it works.

Comment: [Which iomanip manipulators are 'sticky'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky) is handy to know.

Comment: For education purposes read through [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Comment: So the extra character I see is an extra `-` in the last line.  Compare these two:
First line: `cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(80) << "|" << endl;`
Last line: `cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(80) << "-" << "|" << endl;`
See the extra `<< "-"` in the last line?  Also `E` and `F` have no space after them like the other letters.